# Angular 2 component from url

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'am working on an angular 5 project with a java microservices backend. One of the microservices serves an HTML page that will serve a a component in another angular 5 based page. However I can't seem to find a way to include a HTML page as a component in angular 5. What I want to do is include page 1 as a component in page 2, page 2 will only know the url of page 1. Can someone tell me what the appropriate way to do this is?

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared your folder structure, so let us assume you use angular-cli default structure.

In src/app/app.component.html/ts/css is like your root component node.

In a terminal, (in one directory above src, your entire folder) you can use angular-cli commands to create components.

```
ng g c component2 

ng g c component2/component1
```

Edit `component1` and `component2` html as necessary.
Then you can add them to the page by adding to `app.component.html`

```
<app-component2> </app-component2>
```

Then in `component2.html`

```
<app-component1> </app-component1>
```